# Finding cars that a particular battery is compatible with

Tags: battery

I want to find which cars a particular battery (24F - 750 cold cranking amps, 925 cranking amps) is compatible with.  How can I look this up?

Comment: Many thousands of different cars can use a 24F battery, and tractors, and trucks, and motorboats, and airport tugs, and man-lifts, and forklifts, and nobody knows how many other types of equipment. I'm not sure anyone maintains such a list, since it'd be so huge and various and always guaranteed incomplete. Do you have a particular reason for asking, or are you just curious?

Comment: If you can find an automotive battery application guide in spreadsheet format, just sort by battery type and there's your answer.

Comment: Paul - Obviously.  My question isn't about sorting, it's about getting the data.  :)

Comment: Could you be more specific about why you're asking?  What's the specific problem that you're trying to solve?  Or are you just curious?

Comment: Hi Matt - the way it works is that all cars are compatible **except** those that specifically list otherwise (for reasons of size, extra current requirements etc) so there is no list held (as far as I am aware) for which cars a particular battery is compatible with. Just no need for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is a **lot**

[You can look in this battery guide (PDF)](http://www.batteryplex.com/sheets/BCI_21170_Combined_with_Cover.pdf), and use control + F to find the 292 instances of 24F in the application guide.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer of the battery you have will almost certainly have a web site with all the technical information on it. Usually though when you have a particular vehicle or piece of plant you look up the battery for it, the opposite way round to what you are asking.